# Blank space in data loaded with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm loading data from a table called "productos" from my database, my application is something like this; When I type a code like IOI000000IO and press Tab, I took that code and check if the product exists, if it is, It put all data in different inputs, at this point work nicely, but the problem is that next to data there's a blank space, so by example one of the input load a descripcion and it looks somethig like this:

[image]

my PHP file make this when a variable called "action" is posted with value of "getdes"

```
 case 'getdes':
            $getd = $almacen->descripcion(Input::get("codigoactual"));
            echo $getd->descripcion;
            break;
```

my Js send the code of the product

```
function getDes() {
    var codigoactual = $(document.activeElement).closest("tr").find(".codigop").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PeticionesAjax.php",
        async: false,
        data: {codigoactual:codigoactual, action: "getdes"},
        success: function(data){
            $(document.activeElement).closest("tr").find(".campossurtirdescr").text(data);
        }
    });
  }
```

hope you can help me

Comment: are we suppose to guess whats happening on your end? post the codes

Comment: sorry i miss the code, now question it's updated.

Comment: Are you sure the form input element doesn't already contain spaces to start with? Where's the input for it?

Comment: I'm not using a form I'm using a table, so every input it's inside a td tag.

Comment: i think that would erase ALL of the blank spaces and for description value that's not very good

Comment: @DaveSanchez or use `trim()`, by the way just check if this contains unneeded spaces `var_dump($getd->descripcion);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the input for "description" is a TextArea. There is no white space within a TextArea tag - it all becomes part of the value. So you can either trim the space from the textarea or use PHP's trim () function to remove it on the server.

Comment: yes, you right I just add $.trim() to data and solved the problem, but i still wondering why does php add a blank space, anyway now it works, thank you.